# Blender UV Edge Artifact

Tags: uv

the first image is of my mesh with all faces selected, and the corresponding uvs. The shader effect I want is a simple gradient based on the uv y-coordinate (for export to unity).

[image]

The second and third images are in blender and unity, respectively, showing an artifact where the edge is brighter than the interior of the faces. Both fragment shaders (in blender and unity) only return uv.y * color so the edges should not be brighter than the face interiors.

[image]

[image]

What could be causing these bright edges? There is no lighting in either of these scenes, and the shaders do not use the normals or lighting at all, just returning (uv.y * color). As the error appears also in the unity view, I know it is a problem with the input uv's, and is not some random blender view display setting.

I did notice that when I select "UV Sync Selection" extra points appear in the UV coordinate grid, and I cannot select these points individual - they appear to be tied to faces. Is this causing some issue somehow? I am not sure what these apparently extra vertices are. The image below shows the same UV layout, with the "UV Sync Selection" toggled on.

[image]

In any case, thank you for your time and any suggestions.

Comment: Did you apply the scale to your object and UV unwrap it?

Comment: I did apply all transforms, including scale. I unwrapped it and set the uv's for each vertex to (0,y) where y is their appropriate height. Maybe I am treating the uvs too much like just some input data and I need to change my unwrapping process?

Comment: A UV map is a flat surface. There's no concept of 'height' on the map itself. It just has X and Y coordinates for 'width' and 'length'. Suggest you watch a few UV unwrapping and texturing videos! [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/introduction.html#introduction) is the Blender manual introduction to UV unwrapping.

Comment: for the height, I remap the height of each vertex to the range of [0,1] so if my object has vertices from (x,0,z) to (x,10,z) and a vertex is located at (x,7,z) I would make the uv coordinate (0,0.7) - this way the relative object height is saved in the uv data so I can make a shader that makes a vertical gradient. I am not going to use any textures. I will read through the blender documentation - thank you for the link.